# duplication of option value on datalist in html

Tags: html

I used HTML datalist for auto completion. My code is:

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser"/>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer"></option>
  <option value="Firefox"></option>
  <option value="Chrome"></option>
  <option value="Opera"></option>
  <option value="Safari"></option>
</datalist>
```

When I execute the above code, the first option will shown more than one times.
Can you say Why the duplication occurring?? 
http://jsfiddle.net/y84pphy9/

Comment: What browser you are using? Works fine in Chrome 45.

Comment: it is working fine @rose

Comment: ok.. Got it. It's my browser problem.